# setting usb communication speed

Tags: usb, usb-drive, usbserial

I would like to implement usb communication at a speed of 30Mbit/sec. My hardware support "high speed usb" so the hardware platform will not limit me.

- Can I implement this speed using USB CDC class, or Mass storage class, or are these usb classes speed limited?
- In USB protocol who determines the bit rate, is it the device?

Answer (score 0):

The USB CDC and mass storage classes do not have any kind of artificial speed limiting, so you can probably get a throughput of 30 Mbps on a high-speed USB connection (which uses 480 Mbps per second for timing bits on the wire).  The throughput you get will be determined by how much bus bandwidth is being used by other devices and how efficiently your device-side firmware, host-side driver, and host-side software operate.

The bit rate is mostly determined by the device.  The device basically signals to the host what USB speeds it supports, and the host picks one.  The full story is a little bit more complicated, and there are a lot more details about how that works in the USB specification.

Comment: Thanks David.

So if I need to implement this most of the software effort would be on the host side? Would the device code need to be modified as well to support this?